# Problem with pulling data from mongoDB object in frontend for node server. (JavaScript/EJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ejs

I'm trying to render a mongoDB object but it's not doing what I'm trying to accomplish.

My code (ejs):

```
<% for(let date in data) { %>
          <% let parsedDate = Date.parse(date); %>
          <% let totalTime = 0; %>
          <% if(isNaN(parsedDate)) { %>             
              <p> <%= date %> is not date </p>
          <% } else { %> 
            <p> <%= date %> is a date </p>
            <% for(subject in data[date]) { %>
              <p> subject:  <%= subject %> time: <%= data[date][subject].time %> description: <%= data[date][subject].description %> </p>
              <% totalTime += parseInt(subject.time) %>
             <% } %>
            <p> <%= totalTime %></p>
          <% } } %>
```

The output:

[image: The output]

As you can see nothing but a 0 shows up. Why even does the 0 show up? The objects name is "Test".

What my database looks like:

[image: database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

This is the correct code:

```
<% for(date in data) { %>
          <% let parsedDate = Date.parse(date); %>
          <% let totalTime = 0; %>
          <% if(isNaN(parsedDate)) { %>             
              <p> <%= date %> is not date </p>
          <% } else { %> 
            <p> <%= date %> is a date </p>
            <% for(subject in data[date]) { %>
              <% for(element in data[date][subject]) { %>
              <p> subject:  <%= data[date][subject][element].name %> time: <%= data[date][subject][element].time %> description: <%= data[date][subject][element].description %> </p>
              <% totalTime += parseInt(data[date][subject][element].time) %>
             <% } } %>
            <p> <%= totalTime %></p>
          <% } } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you already have the date value in the loop to access info from it use date.date or date.time, or to loop on properties instead using data[date][subject] use for(subject in data[date]) and then access info using subject.time